# Moodle integration questions

Tags: integration, moodle, moodle-api

We are checking all the paths to integrate a .Net application with Moodle, we would like to redirect our .net application users to Moodle so they can take some courses there but I have some questions:

1. Is it required to create a user for each account so they can enroll in a course in Moodle? I mean is it possible to have "**anonymous**" students taking courses in Moodle?
2. We would like to authenticate our users from our .Net application and redirect them directly to a course in Moodle, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. In Moodle there is the concept of *guest access*, with which not registered users can access the system and possibly be enrolled into courses. More information [here](https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Guest_access).
2. Yes. You can use an authentication plugin of Moodle in order to access Moodle from other systems. There are many possibilities here. More details [here](https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=21).